# how to highlight the bars in stacked bar chart of chart.js on clicking a legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a stacked bar chart, I want highlight the bars when a legend of that color is clicked. Say, if I click a legend of color "Green", I want to highlight all the bars in green may be by setting border color to some different color and width like that.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the clicked legend by this code. then you can select the same legend. I have created something similar like this with help of SO.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('yourChartDiv'); 
var myChart = new Chart(canvas, chartData);


canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
   var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
   var data = activePoint._chart.data;
   var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
   var lagend = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label; 
   //var value = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[activePoint._index];
};

console.log(legend); // here is the legend

//Now select the bars with same legend.
```

Hope you can get at least a clue.

Comment: thanks for your reply! What I understood from your code is that you are considering click event on the canvas(on the chart itself). Then you are deriving the legend. But my need is, I am clicking directly on the legend (not on the chart) then I want to highlight the bars that exist in the chart. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible or not mate. But this worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much! today I had another task by that if the user clicks on a bar I have to show relevant content in a table. For that task your answer above was helpful! :)